# The best online resources for full-text searching in Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

So I've learned the difference between [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx), [FREETEXTTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx), [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx), and [CONTAINSTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx).  And I've created a pretty cool search engine that combines a full-text enabled search with a tagging system ([with a little help from you guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317368/how-do-i-avoid-dynamic-sql-when-using-an-undetermined-number-of-parameters)).

But where have you gone to really learn about and master full-text searching and get the most out of it in real-world scenarios?  I'm struggling now with things like database design with full-text indexing in mind, and writing efficient queries that reference multiple tables each with their own full-text-indexed columns.

Any good articles or tutorials you know of are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not an article or a tutorial, but if you're willing to spend a few bucks your single best source of information would be Pro Full-Text Search in SQL Server 2008 by Michael Coles and Hilary Cotter.

http://apress.com/book/view/9781430215943

Comment: You can also take a look at it on Google Books: http://books.google.com/books?id=wGwVkAt79bEC&lpg=PA1&ots=fujGc5fs59&dq=%22sql%20server%202008%22%20%22full%20text%20search%22&pg=PR2#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Comment: Hilary Cotter is da man when it comes to sql full text search!

Answer (score 1):

You could start by going straight to the source (assuming that you haven't already).

- [Full-Text Search (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Search: Internals and Enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269.aspx)