# How to avoid inline SQL when using LIKE clause with variable number of parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a list of 6-digit strings (representing a portion of a Social Security Number), I need to pull back a dataset of users whose SSN matches one of those strings. My SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         u.ssn,
         u.name
FROM user u
WHERE (u.ssn LIKE '%111111%' OR u.ssn LIKE '%222222%')
```

I'd like to use a prepared statement instead of generating inline SQL (injection attacks, etc.) Is there a way I can get my data back without creating inline SQL?

There are [similar questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317368/how-do-i-avoid-dynamic-sql-when-using-an-undetermined-number-of-parameters), but the problem in my case is that using an IN clause instead of LIKE is not an option. I'm only given 6 digits and have to search for the entire 10-digit SSN.

p.s. This is a .Net application with a SQL Server back end.

Comment: Could always prepare your statement for binding and just execute it for each ssn: ...Where u.ssn LIKE '%' || :ssn || '%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your search terms in a table and join them:

```
declare @SSN table (SSN char(9))
insert into @SSN select '123456789' union select '456789321' union select '789123456'

declare @SearchString table (SearchString varchar(9))
insert into @SearchString select '893' union select '9123'

select ssn.SSN
from @SSN ssn
join @SearchString sst on ssn.SSN like '%' + sst.SearchString +'%'
```

If performance is an issue, and if your search strings are always at least 5 characters long (for example), you could create a table with each SSN and every possible 5-character substring. Then you could join the columns on matching values instead of partial values. But again, that depends on your requirements.

Comment: Good solution. And thanks for the tip on performance - we may not need it but it's good to know.